# What is the best way in Python to call the same function in separate threads?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-multithreading

What is the best way to call same *function* in separate threads and have a separate  list with returned values for each instance, without duplicating *function*?

Example:

```
import threading


def function(a):

    returned_values = []

    ct = threading.currentThread() 
    while getattr(ct, "do_run", True):
        ret = do_something(a)
        returned_values.append(ret)


t1 = threading.Thread(target=function, args=("AAA",))
t2 = threading.Thread(target=function, args=("BBB",))
t3 = threading.Thread(target=function, args=("CCC",))

t1.start()
t2.start()
t3.start()

import time;time.sleep(10)
t1.do_run = t2.do_run = t3.do_run = False
```

EDIT: Forgot to mention that I use Python 2.7

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use threading in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846653/how-to-use-threading-in-python)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use ThreadPool

Something like this

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

pool = ThreadPool()
pool.map(function, list_containing_args)
```

P.S `it works similar to multiprocess map.Each argument is given a new thread .You can specify the number of threads you want to spawn if you have limited resources or a big list`

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
import subprocess
def func(ip):
    c=subprocess.Popen("ping -c 3 "+ip, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output, error= c.communicate()
    return output

pool = ThreadPool()
for i in  pool.map(func,["127.0.0.1", "www.google.com", "www.facebook.com"]):
    print i
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you please explain a bit how this works?

Comment: Is there a reason why I would use ThreadPool instead of multiprocessing.Pool class?

Comment: @rbs ThreadPool will launch `threads` which are relatively easy and cheap if you are doing `IO` related work.If you use `multiprocess` it will launch `Processes` which have overheads.So if your task involves `IO` use `threads` else `processes`

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Using ThreadPool doesn't make the threads share the same memory space of the function? Isn't this going to impact how the separate calls to the functions work? And finally, how is this different then using threading?

Comment: @rbs ThreadPool is same as using threads.....Multiprocess.pool.map is different.I think my last comment confused you.Multiprocess is not multiple threads,its multple processes.But mutliprocess has one class Threadpool which uses threads instead of process.

Comment: So where is the difference? Isn't the memory of the function going to be shared if using ThreadPools? Isn't this going to screw up what the function returns for each individual parallel call?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142816/discussion-between-rbs-and-vks).

Comment: @rbs see a working example....It will return a list of all responses...

Comment: [Here's an explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28463266/2327328) of how ThreadPool works

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't a `ProcessPool` here be better suited since threading is best suited for network I/O issues where a `ProcessPool` is best suited for memory intensive tasks.

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

with futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=n) as executor:
    executor.map(fn, args)
```

Comment: Why is this answer ignored? Is it a bad pattern, is there any issue in using this, or is it simply more common to use the pattern of the chosen answer?

Comment: @EduardoPignatelli this is not there in Python 2.7

Comment: @vks you can install it for Python 2.7 if needed so your statement is not exactly accurate

Comment: @aws_apprentice not entirely but true in default state....also person working on python 2.7 will prefer to work with python 2 features I assume

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on `threading`, you may do it like this:

1. Set your arguments in advance

   ```
   n_thread, args_set = 3, [('AAA',), ('BBB',), ('CCC',)]
   ```
2. Store all instances in a list

   ```
   threads = [threading.Thread(target=function, args=args_set[i])
              for i in range(n_thread)]
   [t.start() for t in threads]
   ```
3. Or use `t1`, `t2`, etc..

   ```
   for i in range(n_thread):
       var_thread = locals()['t%d' % i]
       var_thread = threading.Thread(target=function, args=args_set[i])
       var_thread.start()
   print t1, t2
   ```